# Change the source of a link

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet where the last column is always linked to a link. I need to write a code that change the source of this link, where the address is the name of the file ("Caixa das empresas") + the date of yesterday. I tried to write this code, but for some reason its not working.

```
Sub delete_formulas()

Dim LastCol As Integer
Dim DATstr As String
With Worksheets("Calculo")
    LastCol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Columns(LastCol - 1).Copy
Columns(LastCol - 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End With

ActiveSheet.Calculate
DATstr = Format((Date - 1), "mm-dd-yy")
Columns(LastCol).Select
ChDir "T:\Gerencial\Mapa\Tesouraria\Histórico - Caixa das Empresas"


 ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:= _
    "T:\Gerencial\Mapa\Tesouraria\Histórico - Caixa das Empresas\Caixa das empresas.xlsx & DATstr"

End Sub
```

Comment: When you say "its not working" do you mean it is throwing an error?  What error and on which line?

Comment: @user7004 I was also getting  error at `changelink` that's why I changed programming approach. Please go through and experiment with the submitted program and files which in my opinion fully meets your requirements. I do not recollect the error now as it was yesterday worked out and did not keep a note of it. Most probably it related to improper use of method.

Answer (score 2):

You are including the `DATstr` inside the quoted string. It needs to be appended to the right end or stuffed into the middle.

```
ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:= _
    "T:\Gerencial\Mapa\Tesouraria\Histórico - Caixa das Empresas\Caixa das empresas" & DATstr & ".xlsx"
```

Comment: I have already changed this but still not working. The error is located on the "ChangeLink"

Answer (score 0):

The changeLink function needs two arguments : Name and NewName.

Comment: Currently, I have changed what you suggested, but there's still an error in the end of the code. My code is below:

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to suitably adopt to your needs one program version which works as per your requirements. I could get time to just make raw code to meet your requirements.The following code iterates through the Excel links in a workbook and changes links from the test2.xls file to test4 - 09-14-15.xlsx. 
Snapshot of the sample file is given below.

[image: changelink sample file]

I have also uploaded sample file test.xlsm with sample data. You can refer [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qwvro76wfgnbkxr/test.xlsm?dl=0)

Programming approach is different. Try this code :

```
Sub Chnlink()
    Dim link, linkSources, newLink As String
    Dim DATstr As String
    DATstr = Format((Date - 1), "mm-dd-yy")
    newLink = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\test4 - " & DATstr & ".xlsx"
    linkSources = ThisWorkbook.linkSources(xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)
    If IsArray(linkSources) Then
      For Each link In linkSources
         If InStr(link, "test2.xls") Then _
          ThisWorkbook.ChangeLink link, newLink, xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
      Next
    End If
End Sub
```